Using Sharding to Blue / Green MongoDB
I'm investigating how to migrate a critical workload from MongoDB to DocumentDB.
The typical Blue / Green strategy with CDC (AWS DMS) results in a big bang cutover and has lots of risk. I'm exploring other ways to potentially gradually move data from a MongoDB replicaset to a DocumentDB replicaset. Naturally sharding comes to mind as it seems to have all the pieces of moving data from one replicaset to another.
Is it possible to shard mongodb in such a way that all data resides on the blue replicaset, and then update shard keys over time to move data completely to the green replicaset?

In principle sharding would be possible, however I don't think you can but MongoDB and DocumentDB into one cluster.
